# Eleventh Chord in Major and Dominant

Tags: chords, chord-theory

In 11th chords we're adding an *11th* (which is a *4th* above the *octave*) to a given chord:

**Cmin7**: 1 b3 5 b7
**Cmin11**: 1 b3 5 b7 11

**Cmin7b5**: 1 b3 b5 b7
**Cmin7b5/11**: 1 b3 b5 b7 11

I've learned that I should alter the 11th if there is a *IIIma* interval in the chord, because the minnor 9th interval between the *3th* and the *11th*:

**C7**: 1 3 5 b7
**C11**: 1 3 5 b7 #11

**Cmaj7**: 1 3 5 7
**Cmaj11**: 1 3 5 7 #11

But in the web, everywhere I look, a *C11* and *Cmaj11* have a natural *11th* interval.

My question is, what should I play if I come across a C11 chord? Should I alter the *11th* interval, or should I do so only if specified explicitly by (*C(#11)*, *C13(#11)*)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some would say that an eleventh chord should include Root, 3, 5 7 9 and 11. This complicates things a tad more.

For a C11 for instance, it'll be C E G B D F ; Cm11 - C Eb G Bb D F, and Cdom11 - C E G Bb D F.

Because of potential clashes of certain notes, often the 3 and 5 are omitted. This then starts to sound more like a sus chord. It's sometimes written as Gm/C, as the top part is indeed a Gm(7) chord in its own right.

On a guitar or such like, where it's difficult to voice some chords to sound good, certainly the 5th would be left out, and if other players were present, I might even simply play a Gm on top of everything else the others play, for Cdom11 or Cm11. For C11, a G7 would work. So, it's going to be instrument dependent to a degree. On piano, there's more opportunity to spread out the notes, and perhaps use them all and still sound good.

The #11 (or #4) ought to be specified in the chord symbol or name, as it's not expressly part of a chord with just '11' in the name. It needs telling, and it's fun when you see C#11 - is it C (#11) or C# (11)? Been caught out a few times, although context should help.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, C11 contains C, E, G, B♭,D, F.  C(♯11) contains C, E, G, B♭,D, F♯.  Yes, if the base triad is major, it's very likely the 11th will be sharpened.  But then the chord will be written as C(♯11).  Not as C♯11, as @Tim says that's ambiguous.  And quite likely as C7(♯11) or C9(♯11).  But if the ♯11 is required, it will SAY ♯11.

But be careful.  'C11' is often used to mean C7(sus4) or B♭/C or Gm7/C.   Three different chords, none of them actually C11.  But it happens.  A lot.

Comment: but how @Laurence ? How could a C11 Chord be a Csus4 or a major triad chord ?? I mean yeah C F G would result a Csus4 Chord okay got it & for sure a C11 contains also a C major triad, and what is with the other notes like the E the D and the A# ? How you compose the F/C or the Dm7/C ??

Comment: What are you doing with the other Notes, and where do you get the perfect fifth for the Dm7/C since in my Opinion the perfect fifth from D would be A and not A# or Bb

The same applies to F/C how could you build a F/C Chord with an A# Note ?? and what is with the other notes from the C11 ??

Please tell me how you get to that Idea , it would be intensely interesting to me because it doesn't matter in what notion I think of it, I'll never get to a logical conclusion

Comment: @Niko Gürtler Whoops!   I gave examples for G11 rather than C11.   Now corrected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the answer that claims that a C11 chord has the following notes: C E G B D F or in intervals: Root, M3, p5, p7, p9, p11.

In my opinion a C11 chord has also a minor seventh, so it would be C E G A#/Bb D F or in intervals root, M3, p5, b7, p9, p11.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure because in theory the only thing which distinguishes a major chord from a minor chord is the third interval. The screenshot below may help. [image: illustration of C11 on a piano keyboard]

Comment: I think “p7” is supposed to be “M7” in the first paragraph, “b7” is supposed to be “m7” in the second paragraph, and “p9” supposed to be “M9” in both paragraphs.

Comment: @ElementsInSpace there are various naming convention. _Major 7th_ is the same as _natural 7th_, and _minor 7th_ is the same as _flat 7th_. But there is indeed no such thing as _perfect 7th_.